# @override onResume used but screen resets

Tags: java, android, overriding

The java and/or XML file seems to reload on wake from pause but I thought @Override would stop that. How do I stop this from happening?

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Playsound2.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SoundManager.getInstance();
        SoundManager.initSounds(this);
        SoundManager.loadSounds();
    }
```

Perhaps I was unclear. How do I stop the activity restarting on wakeup?

Comment: `@Override` means you override the method from the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onResume Method will be called every time your activity gets Resumed. if you do not want that, use your code in some method of your own apart from activity because activity methods have a life cycle and they follow the same hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

@Override means you override the method from the parent class.

`onResume` is part of the `Activity`'s lifecycle and will be called automatically.